# convert x86 to x64 the linking error(2019) occure

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, visual-c++-6

I have a project in vc++ which using standerd windows library and source file  include file1.h.A method in header file defind as

**file1.h**

> void _stdcall fun(char * text);

but the plateform was the x86 and vc6.Now I converted the project in vs8.and plateform x64.I also add the **file1.lib** file in x64 plateform.But when I execute the project the error occure that

> error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol fun referenced in function
>   main

Comment: You have to rebuild the library too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @Hans said, you need to recompile *everything* to work with x64 (if its not x64 already), this is due to the fact that x64 has a different ABI, thus the name decoration of symbols changes, hence your error.